# Directional derviatives on the Sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:R^{m} \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function, having all directional derivatives. Prove that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u)\ > 0$, for all $u \in S^{m-1}$ then there's a point $a \in R^{m}$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)=0$ for all $v \in R^{m}$

My attempt:

I'm totally lost as to how to use the fact that the directional derivatives on the sphere are positive, I've already found a skecth of the proof, but it's poorly explained.

Comment: Hopefully it's a little bit clearer now.